# How to check if one date period overlapping another date period

Tags: java, if-statement, time, boolean, localdate

So I have this function I created called `isDateOverlapping`. It takes in (of all type `LocalDate`):

- Start Date 1
- End Date 1
- Start Date 2
- End Date 2

What this function does is it tells me if the 2 date periods are overlapping or not.

For example if I have 1 period from `2019-06-15 to 2019-06-18` and another period from `2019-06-15 to 2019-06-12`. It would return true because the 2 date periods overlap.

However my function doesn't seem to always return the right answer. Could you please help.

```
public boolean isDateOverlapping(LocalDate start1, LocalDate end1, LocalDate start2, LocalDate end2) {

    if (start1.isAfter(start2) && start2.isBefore(start1)) {
        return true;

    } else if (end1.isBefore(end2) && start1.isAfter(start2)) {
        return true;
    } else if (start1.isAfter(end1) && end2.isBefore(start2)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Do you consider a period overlapping another one if the last day of the earlier period is exactly the first date of the later one? That is kind of an edge case that should be defined before implementing anything.

Comment: *another period from 2019-06-15 to 2019-06-12* — so a period can go backward? Do you want this treated the same as a period from 2019-06-12 to 2019-06-15?

Comment: For special edge cases like empty intervals etc. see also my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43315879/2491410)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to understand this is two consider the 4 possibilities:

1. the second interval contains the first interval: s2 < s1 < e1 < e2
2. The second interval contains the start of the first interval: s2 < s1 < e2 < e1
3. The second interval contains the end of the first interval: s1 < s2 < e1 < e2
4. The second interval is contained in the first interval: s1 < s2 < e2 < e1

They can be illustrated as follows:

```
        1.                  2.                    3.               4.

|---------------|       |-------|                |------|        |----|     Second Interval
     |-----|                 |------|        |-------|       |-----------|  First Interval
s2   s1    e1   e2      s2   s1 e2  e1      s1  s2   e1 e2   s1  s2  e2  e1
```

The common invariant in all of these 4 cases is that the second interval must start before the first interval ends, and the second interval must end after the first interval begins.

This gives you:

```
public boolean isDateOverlapping(LocalDate start1, LocalDate end1, LocalDate start2, LocalDate end2) {
    return start2.isBefore(end1) && end2.isAfter(start1); 
}
```

Note that you might require a small change if you want your method to return true when the intervals overlap at a single point. In that case, you need to replace `start2.isBefore(end1)` with `!start2.isAfter(end1)` and `end2.isAfter(start1)` with `!end2.isBefore(start1)`.

Also note that I'm assuming `start1 <= end1` and `start2 <= end2`. If that's not always the case, you'll have to check that too, and swap startN with endN, if necessary, before checking the above conditions.

Comment: One question, I thought there are more edge cases? That one line solves the cases?

Comment: @JoeyYue please see my edits

Answer (score 2):

To determine if two date period overlapping only below logic sufficient.

`(StartDate1 <= EndDate2) and (StartDate2 <= EndDate1)`